# Is Iron Man 3's ending based on any canonical source?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-3

At the end of Iron Man 3:

> Tony Stark removes the shrapnel in his chest and the ARC reactor, and destroys all of his armours. However, he ends by saying: "I'm Iron Man"

Does this happen in any other canonical source? And if so, how does the story continue?

Comment: I understand the "I'm Iron Man" thing, and what was meant with that.  My intention with this question was to know if this ending happened in any comic and if it was an ending of the Iron Man series.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Marvel film-verse (including Hulk, Captain America, Thor, & Iron Man movies) has its own canon, separate from the comics.

So the easy answer to your question is "Yes, this is canon for the films," as the film itself is a canonical source.

Outside of that, I believe Tony Stark has gone through many ups and downs in his life in the comics.  Simply destroying the armors and the reactor won't stop him from creating new armor or new reactors in the future.

What I think you're missing is that Tony Stark is making a point - HE is Iron Man.  The armor doesn't make him a hero, it's just a tool.  He's making the same point that he and Rhodie made in Iron Man 2 - it's the person inside the armor that matters, not the armor.

Comment: I see that point but my question was more focused in knowing if the ARC / shrapnel removal has been depicted in any comic. I'll edit my question reflecting this.

Comment: The problem with the question, then, is that the ARC / Shrapnel issue was created for the movie; the whole concept wasn't in the comic to the best of my recollection.

Comment: @KHW the shrapnel is of course a part of canon, the ARC was created for the first film, but has since been incorporated into the main continuity.

Comment: @Monty129 This is answers better my question, could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 11):

It's based off the Extremis storyline in the Iron Man comic just changed a little so it fits with the movie and I think they purposely didn't explain everything so they can reveal the new extremis Tony Stark/Iron Man for Avengers 2.

> Extremis Iron Man
>
> After being critically injured during a battle with
> a nanotech-enhanced foe, Stark injected his nervous system with a
> modified techno-organic virus to save his own life. This fused Stark's
> armor to his body, allowing him to store the inner layers of the Iron
> Man armor in the hollows of his bones as well as control it through
> direct brain impulses. The Extremis enhancement has turned Stark into
> a cyborg, whereby the usage of his existing lockchip (a personal area
> networking implement implanted in his forearm) is directly integrated
> into his nervous system.
>
> His new armor is no longer a bulky unit which houses its own AI
> "response server" and miscellaneous interfaces for neural control.
> Instead, it is more lightweight (constructed of a pliable crystalline
> material with a molecular structure that can collimate into super-hard
> planes upon the application of an electrical field) and less complex
> (as it interfaces directly to Stark's brain via the Extremis-modified
> cybernetic connections), and has much faster response time since it
> effectively functions like Stark's second skin.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man%27s_armor#Iron_Man_Model_30_.28Extremis_Armor.29)</sup>

Comment: +1 This is how I interpreted the ending on Iron Man 3, I'm really hoping to see the extremiss version on Avengers 2

Comment: This is what I assumed too.  "Stabilizes" extremis in Pepper, was too dangerous to remove the shrapnel in the past, but now he can use it on himself to heal quickly so the surgery is safe, blows up the suits because he doesn't need them anymore, says "I *am* Iron Man", etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

The series has ended. The story does not continue in any way. Robert Downey Jr. and Gwyneth Paltrow have stated that the series ends with Iron Man 3. The arc thingy was never used in the comics. Also, he tossed the reactor away. Even if he does use the armor (if he builds one) with an arc reactor fitted inside the armor, it won't matter cause nobody is being stopped from just ripping the reactor away. He created-and used Iron Man. He still remains Iron Man without the armor. The answer to the Question: "Does the man make the suit or the suit makes the man?" is-the man makes the suit. The suit is just a tool, as Jeff said. Only Tony, inside the suit matters. The shrapnel was never removed in the comics because the heart itself was removed and replaced/repaired with artificial tissue. The whole series is a canon.

Comment: So, when at the end of the film you can read "Tony Stark will return", it is meant only for **The Avengers**?

Comment: @Thecafremo Unless Marvel announces Iron Man 4, yes, it's only for Avengers

Comment: Consider: Joss Whedon, infamous for killing off fan-favourite characters for the shock value, is going to direct Avengers 2. He's stated that he's going to do some 'horrible, horrible things' to the characters. Tony Stark, by far the most popular character in the Marvel movieverse, is not going to have any more standalone films...

Comment: @Paul do you have any evidence suggesting that iron man 3 is the last in the series?

Comment: @Paul its stated in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_3#Future), this is not the end of Iron Man series and there is a possible continuation for the same

Comment: Paltrow has said that *she thinks* ["we're done with Iron Man"](http://www.pastemagazine.com/articles/2013/04/the-premiere-of-iron-man.html). Who "we" refers to is not entirely clear. Especially since RDJ says ["I had a long contract with them and now we’re gonna renegotiate"](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/05/01/robert-downey-jr-jon-favreau-iron-man-video_n_3191342.html)

Comment: Producer Kevin Feige: [" Well, no, I think people say that because we’re not developing 'Iron Man 4.' {...} Do I think there will be another Iron Man movie? Of course I do. Who will be in that movie and who will be a part of that movie? Who knows? And how far down the line will it be?"](http://www.superherohype.com/features/articles/176645-exclusive-superherohype-chats-with-marvel-prez-kevin-feige)

Comment: Just because Paltrow and/or Downey say they're not doing any more IM, doesn't mean there won't be any. Maybe Ben Affleck will be Stark in IM4...